# Facebook JS SDK And Share Button Errors

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-share, instant, facebook-instant-games

I am working on a Facebook Instant game and facing some errors.

Here are the errors in the console:

> Refused to frame 'https://staticxx.facebook.com/' because it violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'
>   blob: zynga.com *.zynga.com".
>
> Refused to frame 'https://www.facebook.com/' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' blob:
>   zynga.com *.zynga.com".

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izlhp.png)

All the code used is from Facebook's documentation.

The first error comes with the JS SDK code:

```
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.0&appId=CENSORED&autoLogAppEvents=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

The second error comes with the share button code. The button doesn't show up at all.

```
<div class="fb-share-button"
     data-href="https://gdpalace.wordpress.com/" 
     data-layout="button" 
     data-size="large" 
     data-mobile-iframe="true">
     <a 
        target="_blank" 
        href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fgdpalace.wordpress.com%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse" 
        class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
        Share
    </a>
</div>
```

So, I can't implement a share button at all because it throws that error and doesn't show up. What can I do about this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/instant-games/rich-gameplay-features has a list of what “social features” you can use, and how. (Not sure whether that actually means that you can not use any other, but might be the case. Since this appears in locations such as a user’s news feed, they probably limited what you can do compared to an external website app, for security and other reasons.)

Comment: Thanks. I implemented shareAsync() in my game, and the share dialog seems to work, but I can't click the "post" button to actually share it - it doesn't work. Why? Is it because my app is still in development, or is it a bug?

Comment: Update: shareAsync() only allows personal message sharing in the Messenger app, you can't share on your profile using it. So I can't use that function.

Comment: Documentation explicitly says otherwise …? _“Players can share it in their News Feed or in Messenger conversations. If they share it in their News Feed, they can include a custom message.”_

Comment: Okay, it seems like you can only do personal messaging via the Messenger app. Still though, on PC, I can't hit the Post button to actually share the moment. Why could that be happening?

Comment: If the Share button is not functioning for you, please file a bug at developers.facebook.com/bugs with the URL you are currently on.